# Unable to verify Request originated From Shopify - Cypress

Tags: automation, automated-tests, shopify, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm trying to automate some testcases on Shopify store but i'm unable to do so. Here are screenshots [[image: CodeError]

[image: error]

Comment: Do they allow that kind of E2E test? You might be getting blocked due to being bot detected

Comment: That might be a reason but i'll look into it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you find any solution to that? I'm have the same issue! @KnowledgeFacts

Answer (score 0):

I am not much into Cypress, but would changing a user agent be of any help? I know that in web crawling, this is done (in Scrapy), so just checking for the similar idea of whether changing the user agent be of any help here.

Comment: i Did tried that as well- but Cypress didn't allow to do that.